# MEAN-stack, organize structure for game logic

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I’m trying to make a simple card game (like hearthstone) using MEAN stack and socket.io for a game process.

But I have no idea how to better organize the structure of the **server-side**.

I have the following structure:

- server/

  - models/ (Database Schema models)

    - player.js
    - card.js
    - deck.js
  - controllers/

    - player.js
    - card.js
    - deck.js
  - routes/ (REST api)

    - player.js
    - card.js
    - deck.js
- server.js (main)

Here I has implemented manipulation with players', cards' and decks' data using HTTP-requests.

But I can't understand, where I have to realize the logic of the game. So I have the following questions:

1. Where should I implement the game logic for player and cards, for example, the actions that occur when one card attacking another?
2. Where should I implement the main part of game logic, which includes player interaction (using socket.io), change of game state and so on?

UPD: Or (and) share some github projects.

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have to implement the logic in the controllers. After an action in the front-end you perform a call to server-side routes that call a function in controller where you have to write the logic.
2. for the general logic of the game you can create a "core" module.